# How to keep all intermediate property variables in a deeply nested destructure

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs

Given this:

```
var metadata = {
    title: 'Scratchpad',
    translations: [
       {
        title: 'JavaScript-Umgebung'
       }
    ]
};

const output = ({
  title: englishTitle,
  translations: [{
    title: localeTitle
  }]
}) => (
    console.log(englishTitle), // "Scratchpad"
    console.log(localeTitle)  // "JavaScript-Umgebung"
)

output(metadata);
```

Now `translations` is undefined:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(translations))  // ❌ "undefined"
```

*Question*: Is there a way to create a variable `translations` within the params destructure expressions (e.g. within the function param parenthesis)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can destructure translations as well as it's inner members:

```js
var metadata = {
    title: 'Scratchpad',
    translations: [
       {
        title: 'JavaScript-Umgebung'
       }
    ]
};


const output = ({
  title: englishTitle,
  translations, // get translations
  translations: [{
    title: localeTitle
  }]
}) => (
    console.log(englishTitle), // "Scratchpad"
    console.log(localeTitle),  // "JavaScript-Umgebung"
    console.log(translations)  // [{ title: 'JavaScript-Umgebung' }]
)

output(metadata);
```

Comment: Oh wow, I should of tried that >_<

Comment: @AshleyCoolman - it's not intuitive to destructure the same thing twice.